# Regex match all non letters excluding diacritics (python)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, regex-negation

I have found this excellent guide: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category that gives some hints on how to match **non** letters with the following regex:

```
\P{L}
```

But this regex will consider non letters also `à` encoded as U+0061 U+0300 (if I understood well). 
For example using [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module in python the following snippet:

```
all_letter_doc = regex.sub(r'\P{L}', ' ', doc)
```

will transform `purè` in `pur`

In the guide is provided how to match all letters with the following:

```
\p{L}\p{M}*+
```

and in practice I need the negation of that but I do not know how to obtain it.

Comment: Try `ur'\P{L}'` and replace with `u' '`. In case you want to replace all chars other than letters and diacritics with space, you will need `[^\p{L}\p{M}]+` regex

Comment: excellent, just explain in the answer why it works and I will accept. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2.x, your `r'\P{L}'` is a byte string, while the input you have is Unicode. You need to make your pattern a Unicode string. See the [PyPi `regex` reference](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

> If neither the `ASCII`, `LOCALE` nor `UNICODE` flag is specified, it will default to `UNICODE` if the regex pattern is a Unicode string and `ASCII` if it’s a bytestring.

Thus, you need to use `ur'\P{L}'` and a `u' '` replacement pattern.

In case you want to match 1+ chars other than letters and diacritics, you will need `ur'[^\p{L}\p{M}]+'` regex.